# I am attempting to use google app engine (python) to save a url with # character

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My class looks like this:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    link = db.LinkProperty()
```

I am getting the url parameter and populating the class like this:

```
newpost = Post(
link = cgi.escape(self.request.get('link')))

newpost.put()
```

If I send a regular link it works fine.
If I send a link like this (with a hash):  http://www.url.com#paragraph2, it chokes.

Has anyone dealt with this before?  Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hash component of a URL is never sent to the server.

This behavior is used in [some AJAX patterns](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs) because of this property.

I would recommend URL-encoding the hash in the URL to `%23`:

`http://example.com/whatever%23afterHash`

Comment: I need to save the complete URL to the database, including the hash.  Any suggestions on how to properly escape it so that I get everything saved?

Answer (score 0):

If db.LinkProperty won't work, just use db.StringProperty.